# How to use X509SigningCredentials with System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader?

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I want to create my own JWT Token using Microsoft IdentityModel. This library seems to be good but not enough documented :-(

So my problem is I don't know how to convert X509SigningCredentials into SigningCredentials, so I can't create JwtHeader ...

Here my code :

```
public void GenereToken()
    {

        var certThumbPrint = "ACCB5050C2591FF9CB9F90D71D8B96BE13DC9320"; 
        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine); 
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbPrint, false);
        certStore.Close();

        var header = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtHeader(new X509SigningCredentials(certCollection[0]));

        var payload = new JwtPayload
        {
            {"iss", "a5ghgde64-e8g4d-48ga-beg1-56e293d09a69"},
            {"scope", "example.com"},
            {"aud", "example.com"},
            {"iat", 1441698079}, 
        };

        var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        var cielToken = handler.WriteToken(secToken)

    }
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GenereToken();

        }


        public static void GenereToken()
        {

            var certThumbPrint = "95 2f 5e ca 7c d0 a3 f0 6c ca 7d e4 0a 24 7a 2c c3 42 f5 f6";
            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbPrint, false);
            certStore.Close();

            var securityKey = new X509SecurityKey(certCollection[0]);
            var algorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
            var header = new JwtHeader(new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(securityKey, algorithm));

            var payload = new JwtPayload
            {
                {"iss", "a5ghgde64-e8g4d-48ga-beg1-56e293d09a69"},
                {"scope", "example.com"},
                {"aud", "example.com"},
                {"iat", 1441698079},
            };

            var secToken = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var cielToken = handler.WriteToken(secToken);

        }
    }
}
```

And the content of packages.config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

I used [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451132(v=vs.114).aspx) to get algorithm name.

Comment: However I would like to remove 'kid' and 'type' attributes in my header {
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "ACCB5050C2591FF9CB9F90D71D8B96BE13DC9320",
  "typ": "JWT"
}. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: @Cooxkie `header.Remove("kid");` maybe :)